# Правильное построение url в Template Django

Tags: django

Использую MPTT
Хочу сделать:
Страницы категорий - отображают построчно содержащие подкатегории (если имеются, если нет, то список продуктов находящихся в самой категории) и список содержащих в себя продуктов.
Страницы подкатегорий - отображают только входящие в себя продукты
Глубина больше 2-х уровней пока не планируется.
Страницы описания товара (если есть подкатегория, то путь прим. 
category/subcategory/product, если есть только категория то category/product, соответственно)
Но столкнулся с проблемой, не могу разместить ссылки на товарах, так что бы они из категорий и подкатегорий вели к странице описания товара.
При попытки указать в шаблоне на карточке товара, которая отображается в Категориях.

```
{% url 'product' category_slug subcategory_slug product_slug %}
```

Получаю
`Reverse for 'product' with arguments '('mangaly', '', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category_slug>[^/]+)/(?P<subcategory_slug>[^/]+)/(?P<product_slug>[^/]+)/$']` 
Но по факту понимаю, что тут еще 1 ошибка, как дать понять django, что я хочу вызвать путь `category/product` в дальнейшем?

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('<category_slug>/', views.category, name='category'),
    path('<category_slug>/<subcategory_slug>/', views.subcategory, name='subcategory'),
    path('<category_slug>/<subcategory_slug>/<product_slug>/', views.product, name='product'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound


def category(request, category_slug):
    cat = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(
        is_active=True), slug=category_slug).get_descendants(include_self=True)
    cat_list = Category.objects.filter(is_active=True, slug=category_slug).get_descendants(include_self=True)
    subcat_list = Category.objects.filter(is_active=True, slug=category_slug).get_descendants(include_self=False)
    subcat_list = subcat_list.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id')
    cat_prod = Product.objects.filter(category__in=cat_list).distinct()

    return render(request, 'products/category.html', locals())


def subcategory(request, subcategory_slug, category_slug):
    subcat = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(
        is_active=True, children__isnull=True),
        slug=subcategory_slug)
    cat = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(is_active=True), slug=category_slug)
    prod = Product.objects.filter(category=subcat)
    cat_prod = Product.objects.filter(category__parent=cat)

    if subcat.parent == cat:
        return render(request, 'products/subcategory.html', locals())
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Error 404')


def product(request, subcategory_slug, category_slug, product_slug):
    prod = get_object_or_404(Product.objects.filter(is_active=True), slug=product_slug)
    subcat = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(
        is_active=True, children__isnull=True),
        slug=subcategory_slug)
    cat = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(is_active=True), slug=category_slug)

    return render(request, 'products/product_page/mangal_page.html', locals())
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
import mptt


# Категория товара
class Category(MPTTModel):
    meta_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Underground')
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='Underground')
    text_description = RichTextField(default='Underground', verbose_name='Главный текстовый блок',
                                     help_text='Главный текстовый блок на странице КАТЕГОРИЙ')
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, blank=None, null=False, default=None,
                            verbose_name='Категория', )
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
                            related_name='children',
                            verbose_name='Родительский класс', )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=None, blank=None, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория товара'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории товаров'

    # Получаем список Слагов
    def get_slug_list(self):
        try:
            ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
        except:
            ancestors = []
        else:
            ancestors = [i.slug for i in ancestors]
        slugs = []
        for i in range(len(ancestors)):
            slugs.append('/'.join(ancestors[:i + 1]))
        return slugs


mptt.register(Category, order_insertion_by=['name'])

# Продукт
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, default=None,
                            verbose_name='Наименование')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, default=0, verbose_name='Цена')
    price_by_discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, default=0, verbose_name='Цена по скидкой')
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Скидка', help_text='Считается автоматически!!!',
                                   editable=False)
    image = models.ImageField(unique=True, upload_to='product_images/', blank=None, null=False, default=None,
                              verbose_name='Основное фото')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                              related_name='cat',
                              verbose_name='Категория товара')
    description = RichTextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True, default=None, verbose_name='Описание',
                                help_text='Для страницы продукта 1000 символов')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=None, blank=None, default='')
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Просмотры')
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, verbose_name='Обновлено')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name='Создано')

    # discount count
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.price_by_discount > 0:
            self.discount = self.price / self.price_by_discount * 100 - 100
            print(self.discount)

            super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'
```

В общем смущает `urls.py`

Comment: Так вы их не передали в шаблон

Comment: А Вас не затруднит подсказать на данном примере, как это правильно сделать, просто я новичок к этом деле, я был бы Вам очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def product(request, subcategory_slug, category_slug, product_slug):
    prod = get_object_or_404(Product.objects.filter(is_active=True), slug=product_slug)
    subcat = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(
        is_active=True, children__isnull=True),
        slug=subcategory_slug)
    cat = get_object_or_404(Category.objects.filter(is_active=True), slug=category_slug)
    context = {
        'subcategory_slug': subcategory_slug,
        'category_slug': category_slug,
        'product_slug': product_slug,
        'subcat': subcat,
        'prod': prod,
        'cat': cat
    }
    return render(request, 'products/product_page/mangal_page.html', context)
```

Comment: Они же вроде бы через local() все передавались? Я понял, что я не правильно выводил {% url 'product' category_slug subcategory_slug product_slug %}, теперь моя проблема заключается в том, что мне при разных условиях надо передавать слаг на категории, в одном случае он должен быть просто category_name/ а в другом category_name/subcategory_name/, вот как запихнуть это условие в один параметр в urlpatterns? Вроде бы и что то подобное получается построить за счет def get_slug_list, но как его вывести правильно не могу пока вразумить :( В любом случае огромное спасибо за отзывчивость